# Material Components version 1.1.0 flicker when hiding fab/showing menu item in BottomAppBar

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to show a `MenuItem` when the application's `fab` is hidden in the `BottomAppBar`, and make it visible again when I show the `fab`. When I am hiding the `fab` and making the `MenuItem` visible, however, the former flickers shortly (appears, disappears, and then appears again and stays). In the dependencies of my `Manifest` I have added: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`.

For this example, I have created a button that shows/hides the `fab`.

My `MainActivity` looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private MenuItem menuItm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomAppBar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    }

    public void showHideFab(View view) {
        if (fab.isOrWillBeHidden()) {
            fab.show();
            menuItm.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            fab.hide();
            menuItm.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menuItm = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_itm);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

The layout file `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="end" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:onClick="showHideFab"
            android:text="Show/Hide Fab" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My `menu/menu_main.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.teka.loulis.print.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_itm"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

My `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and the declaration of the `MainActivity` in the `Manifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the version 1.0.0, this issue did not exist. Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug/feature of the library? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I noticed that when the `fab` is aligned in the centre (by removing `app:fabAlignmentMode="end"` from the `activity_main` layout file), this problem is gone. When aligning in the end, other issues exist, for example, if I make the `fab` and the menu item visible at the same time, the menu item is sometimes drawn on top of the `fab`! Seems more like a bug to me.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No. It seems like a bug, so I am waiting for the fix. I already reported it, but it did not get any attention.

Answer (score 3):

With 1.3.0-alpha02 `setFabAlignmentModeAndReplaceMenu()` has been added.

```
bottomAppBar.setFabAlignmentModeAndReplaceMenu(BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END, R.menu.sample)
```

Using this, I am no longer experiencing the flickering effect.

Here is the [commit:d4a5702](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/d4a5702319b9f300b2b782f9b4d45d764d5765b3) on [GitHub: material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) for further information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please also provide a small code sample, based on the above code?